# How to make all posts have a permalink with custom format "domain.com/blog/title"?

Tags: jekyll, static-site

What I'm trying to do is get all my posts to have the following format: domain.com/blog/title.

However, in my `_posts` folder I have a file named `2010-07-11-hello.markdown` and it contains the following:

```
---
title: Hello
permalink: /blog/:title/ 
---
Hello World!
```

What am I doing wrong? The permalinks aren't being converted. For example, the URL looks like this: `http://localhost:4000/blog/:title/` and I want the actual title to show up there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should move the permalink setting into the _config.yml file as described at http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Comment: +1 IIRC the `permalink` setting from the YAML Front Matter isn't interpolated; it's used exactly as typed. Only the `_config.yml` setting is interpolated.

Comment: @brandon this is the piece I was missing, and thanks for adding it. I don't know if I would have understand why, or how to make it work without this helpful comment.

Comment: @MichelleTilley this behavior has now changed, and `permalink` in YAML FrontMatter is interpolated as well (tested in `3.0.2`)