# Configuring per-directory permalink settings in jekyll

Tags: configuration, permalinks, jekyll

Is it possible to have different permalink settings for different directories?

For example, if I have a Jekyll setup where blog entries are written into `/blog/_posts/` and news items in `/news/_posts`, then by default each entry will have permalinks in the format `/blog/2011/06/24/slug.html` and `/news/2011/06/24/slug.html`.

The permalinks for blog entries are fine as they are, but I need to change the permalinks format for news to something different, say `/news/2011/slug`.

I've tried changing the `permalink` settings in the YAML front matter for the layout used by news item, however, this does not work since permalink settings in YAML front matter are not interpolated ([as confirmed in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286964/115845)).

Is there a mechanism to configure path specific settings in `_config.yaml`? Or is there a better what to achieve this results?

Comment: Have you tried `defaults: - scope` in `_config.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve that is by having two different jekyll instances.

You could have (for example) a full site with the pages and blogs, and a "microsite" inside the news folder, with it's own ´_config.yaml´ . The "top" would have to ignore the news directory completely, and the news directory would have to be configured to generate its output inside "../_site/news".

The biggest hurdle would be that you would not be able to run Jekyll as a server; you would have to use a script (i.e. a Rakefile) to generate the static pages for both jekylls, and serve them with a different server (i.e. unicorn).

Like I said, it'd be a bit of a hurdle, but doable in 1h or less.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to avoid. Looks like there isn't a way around it, huh. +1 for now. Will accept if nothing new comes along. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will be any help now but I ran into the same problem trying to make a blog/portfolio and wanting to have /articles/2013/.. and /work/2013/..

What I did is just change the permalink to:

```
permalink: /:categories/:year/:title
```

and added 'articles' as a category for my blog posts and 'work' as a category for my work and it worked fine.

Comment: This doesn't work if a post has several categories. They will be listed in URL. That would look disgusting. Is the way to use only 1st category?

Answer (score 2):

Just got inspired by jose's comment. Why not do this:

```
permalink: /:categories/:title
```

and then in the front matter for your blog just do

```
categories: blog 2013 05 01
```

for news only do

```
categories: news 2013
```