# Stackoverflow-like permalinks with Jekyll

Tags: url, stack-overflow, jekyll, permalinks

I really have taken a liking to Stackoverflow's permalinks. The way I understand them to work is as follows:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/uniqueid/post-title-for-seo
```

The following gets the job done too [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721310/stackoverflow-like-permalinks-with-jekyll):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/uniqueid
```

Interestingly, if you put anything after `uniqueid` you will get to the question

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100001/hello-world
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100001/hello-cruel-world
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100001/hello-strange-world
```

All of the above work, this allows you to change the question's title without losing all your permalinks.

I'm using jekyll and I plan to launch on github with github-pages (which doesn't allow `.htaccess`). If it can be done with jekyll without github-pages (which I'm sure is much easier) then I'd be willing to deploy it to a hosted VPS. I'm open to any solution!

I would also like `questions` to be a specific variable in the post like `post.category` or `post.template` such as `blog` or `portfolio`.

Comment: If you're willing to have an .htaccess file, you can just do this using a rewrite rule http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html (no need for an expensive VPS by the way, Jekyll will give you a lightweight static site you could still host for free, e.g. a nearlyfreespeech.net, etc

Comment: Um, I know it's commonly stated that Github doesn't support .htaccess, but perhaps that applies only to creating secure pages, etc with .htaccess.  It seems to be obeying my mod-rewrite rules for links (e.g. 404 page, removing the htmls, etc) here: http://cboettig.github.com/index

Comment: @cboettig Thanks, I gota try this out!

Comment: Ah, clarification on the github side, my rules just happen to match the default rules. https://help.github.com/articles/custom-404-pages.  still, should be able to use an .htaccess solution on other servers

Comment: @cboettig Can you provide an answer including the `.htaccess` configuration for what I want? I would be glad to accept the answer.

Comment: Linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468566/configuring-per-directory-permalink-settings-in-jekyll , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286964/jekyll-permalinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only close this I found in [Jekill Docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) is to define permalink in every post:

```
---
layout: share
title: CoffeeScript Spaces and Tabs
date: 2013-09-17
categories: [coffee, eclipse, nodeclipse, enide, studio, monster]
permalink: /share/coffeescript-spaces-and-tabs
---
```

I see no trace of post ID concept in Jekyll. I hope someone can suggest how to do that with [variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) or some other way.